# Why was the question about the difference between an Intel i7 and Xeon processor closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, down-votes

> #### [Are there noticeable differences in Intel i7 and Xeon 5400 chipset family? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/330818/are-there-noticeable-differences-in-intel-i7-and-xeon-5400-chipset-family)

Initially, I may have phrased the question incorrectly but was essentially getting to the primary question of the reason an i7 is rated better than a Xeon even though one is typically much more expensive than the other and comparing specific instances from cpubenchmark.net

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/330818/are-there-noticeable-differences-in-intel-i7-and-xeon-5400-chipset-family) has almost no variance from [What is the difference between an Intel i7 and a Xeon quad core processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/122914/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intel-i7-and-a-xeon-quad-core-processor) other than asking for greater detail the the OP of the latter post. The latter gets 19 upvotes and 37k views. I give specific types of actions a user may be interested (gaming is not a SU question in my opinion) so listing out actual day to day activities seems relevant.

In addition to this, the question, which is a valid QUESTION, is downvoted as opposed to vote for being closed. I see things like this quite often, it would be nice to have expalanation for closure as well as consistency across the platform.

Comment: By the way, I believe the word you were looking for is *idiocy* (extremely stupid behavior), not *idiocracy* (a movie).

Answer (score 6):

The other question is now very old, well over a year. The FAQ for Super User has changed in that time. You have listed what you use it for, gearing this to be a shopping question so that the reasons why you should buy it would be outlined.

> e.g. i7 920 has a 5,566 rating whereas the 'best' e5400 process - the
>   Intel Xeon E5450 @ 3.00GHz is listed at a 4201 rating

Comparing products also makes it a shopping question. Although you did modify it slightly, it is still geared to shopping.

Calling us "idiots" for closing your question doesn't help keep it open, by the way. And just because others posted questions that are against the FAQ, doesn't mean you can now.

Answer (score 4):

First, the downvotes are likely a result of your aggressive response to the closing of your question, I know it is frustrating to have a question closed, but insulting those involved is simply the wrong way to object to a closure - edit, flag for a mod to reopen or come straight to meta.

I have now cleaned up many of the comments on the question, and someone already removed the pointless footer you added to the question, they weren't useful to anyone and would have just brought more grief.

---

Second, complete consistency across the platform isn't going to happen, for example just look at sites like Skeptics or Programmers, which have much bigger rule differences (stricter answer requirements and subjective  questions, respectively).

---

Finally, I can't see how the question can be worded to pull it away from a shopping/product recommendation without also then making it a duplicate of the question you have already linked to.

The really over-the-top generalisation would be along the lines of "how do you compare CPUs?", but it looks like you know that already given the benchmark scores you've looked up, and I'm not really sure that would be helpful to you.